# If all the points on my graph fit on a logarithmic and polynomial trend line, how do i justify which trend line i should use?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

My graph is mass of deposit vs concentration. The mass of deposit increases with concentration.

Comment: You need to expand this question and explain the options better. In part it is more of a statistics question than a chemistry one. However I'll grant that models are often based on some chemical/mathematical theory.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases:

If the formula of the theoretical model is known, the approximation follows this formula to determine the formula parameters.

If there is no theoretical model, or the model is not followed, then reasonable empirical formulas are tested and the best fitting and simple enough is chosen.

Aside of polynomials and logarithms, interesting results can be provided by rational functions ( polynomial fractions )

The important thing is to have difference  "number of points" minus "number of parameters", aka degrees of freedom, big enough. This keeps it as an approximation ( usually least squares) rather than an interpolation.